# Recover shared devices Screen Time passcode when using macOS Catalina with an iOS 13.1 device

Tags: mac, ios, macos-catalina

Like a few other unlucky people, I've forgotten my iOS Screen Time passcode. Since I’ve enabled “shared devices” on my iPhone and iPad and updated both to iOS 13.1 [pinfinder.net](https://pinfinder.net) and other solutions are not available. Screen Time was also activated on my Mac running Mac OS Catalina.

I know at least the probable numbers the passcode consists of. Thus, if not for an exact speedy solution I looking for at least an option to skip the waiting time and brute force guess the combination.

Comment: See if this helps - otherwise it's a total clean install - https://superuser.com/questions/1495418/disable-screentime-on-mac-os-without-knowing-passcode-set-on-another-device

Answer (score 1):

## Try using iOS Restriction Passcode Brute Force

Do you have a backup of your iOS device on your local machine? If so, see about using [ios Restriction PassCode Crack -Python version](https://github.com/yuejd/ios_Restriction_PassCode_Crack---Python-version):

> ios Restriction PassCode Cracker, this version of the application is written with Python programming language,which is used to crack the Restriction PassCode of iphone/ipad. (iphone/ipad 访问限制密码破解)

Also, look at this which is a fork ([iOS Restriction Passcode Brute Force Version](https://github.com/thehappydinoa/iOSRestrictionBruteForce)) of the other tool above:

> This version of the application is written in Python, which is used to crack the restriction passcode of an iPhone/iPad takes advantage of a flaw in unencrypted backups allowing the hash and salt to be discovered.

I successfully used the “ios Restriction PassCode Cracker” to get my screen time passcode.

And FWIW, one of the iOS updates (version 12?) set a restriction passcode for you even if you didn’t set one before. So you are not going crazy if you don’t remember setting a passcode like that. I mean, that is the situation I was in and the passcode that was set for my iPhone wasn’t even a combo of numbers I would have ever willfully set myself.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

**Change the date and time settings on your Mac to skip the screen time penalty thus allowing for fast brute force guessing**

1. If it isn’t already the case make sure on your Mac to enable "share across devices" in screen time settings. This ensures you have the same screen time passcode as your other shared devices.
2. Try out the most likely combinations until you are forced to wait.
3. Change your date and time system preferences and set the time until after the waiting time. Most often that will be 1 hour forward (should your first attempts not succeed).
4. Try out combination after combination, skipping the waiting time by setting the system time forward. Until you finally guess the right one.

This system did also work on ios devices in the past but has been blocked by forcing date and time to be “set automatically.”

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Just now seeing this is self-solved. Very interesting issue here: So you are saying that traditional password restriction brute force tools don’t work with iOS 13.1?

Comment: They work until the next Apple update comes and fixes the security problem. In the future it will most likely be like it was with ios jailbreak in the beginning: a steady cycle of finding and fixing exploits, with steadily increasing waiting times until the next exploit is found.   
My proposed solution, although not as fast as others, is should be version and tool independent. At least for now.