# Recover macOS Screen Time Passcode without Apple ID

Tags: macos, mac, password-recovery

My friend (who wishes to remain anonymous in every way) asked me to help them set up screen time on their mac and unfortunately he set a passcode but forgot. They don't have an Apple ID so there is no 'Forgot Password?' button. Also, they are not an administrator so they cannot recover it through an admin account. Is there a way to disable screen time through terminal or find the passcode through the library folders? Thanks.

Edit: My friend has access to an admin account now, what should he do?

Edit Two: What if I find the "com.apple.screentimeagent" and other files and restore them from a backup from before Screen Time was enabled?

Comment: There is no way round this without an iCloud account. The answer below is as good as it gets, I'm afraid. Your friend ignored all safety protocols. With an iCloud account, this works - https://superuser.com/questions/1489760/recover-screen-time-passcode-or-disable-screen-time-sharing-on-mac-os-catalina-a

Answer (score 1):

No. Your friend has ignored all of the retrieval and reset forms for the Password, leaving no other means of resetting the password.

The only thing left is to reset the computer.

Comment: …& hope they didn't also lock the firmware, otherwise it will be a trip to the Apple Store, with the receipt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to backup the device. And then use the Find My app from another apple device to erase the said device. The erasure only needs apple id password.